# Angular - How to modify CSS transform property of HTML elements inside a component directly

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-transforms

I'm trying to create an analog clock for an application I'm currently creating using Angular.

I need to rotate the sec/min/hour handlers over the clock based on the current time, but I don't know how to update the `style.transform` property on each of them.

This is my code so far:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clock',
  templateUrl: './clock.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clock.component.css']
})
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.clock {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #20b7af;
  border: 12px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgb(202, 202, 202);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#sec-hand {
  width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform-origin: 50% 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
}

#min-hand {
  width: 5px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform-origin: 50% 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
}

#hr-hand {
  width: 3px;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform-origin: 50% 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: calc(50% + -2px);
}

.num {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 0.5em);
  font-size: 10px;
}

.num div {
  width: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.num1 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.num1 div {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.num2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.num2 div {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.num3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.num3 div {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.num4 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.num4 div {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.num5 {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.num5 div {
  transform: rotate(-150deg);
}

.num6 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.num6 div {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.num7 {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.num7 div {
  transform: rotate(-210deg);
}

.num8 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.num8 div {
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
}

.num9 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.num9 div {
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
}

.num10 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.num10 div {
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
}

.num11 {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

.num11 div {
  transform: rotate(-330deg);
}

.num12 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.num12 div {
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="clock" #clock>
    <div class="num num1">
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num2">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num3">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num4">
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num5">
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num6">
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num7">
      <div>7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num8">
      <div>8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num9">
      <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num10">
      <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num11">
      <div>11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="num num12">
      <div>12</div>
    </div>
    <div id="hr-hand"></div>
    <div id="min-hand"></div>
    <div id="sec-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a template variable on the different elements like `sec-hand` and then get a reference to it in your component:

```
<div id="sec-hand" #secHand></div>
```

then in your component use `@ViewChild` to get the reference:

```
@ViewChild('secHand') el: ElementRef;
```

and now you can access the DOM element (see working example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbxru?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)).  The example just adds a class so you'll want to check the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) for what you need to accomplish like `setStyle` for transforms.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  @ViewChild('secHand') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'example');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [`refs`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) to the 3 hands, so in your HTML template:

```
<div id="hr-hand" #hrHand></div>
<div id="min-hand" #minHand></div>
<div id="sec-hand" #secHand></div>
```

Then declare and initialize them in your component using [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and use them to update the `transform: rotate(...)` property you need either directly or, even better, using a `Renderer2` renderer, which makes your application more secure against XSS attacks:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-clock',
    templateUrl: './clock.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clock.component.css']
})
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('hrHand') hrHandRef: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('minHand') minHandRef: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('secHand') secHandRef: ElementRef;

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       ...
    }

    updateHands() {
        // Directly (bad):
        // this.hrHandRef.nativeElement.style.transform = `rotate(${ hrAngle }deg)`;
        // this.minHandRef.nativeElement.style.transform = `rotate(${ minAngle }deg)`;
        // this.secHandRef.nativeElement.style.transform = `rotate(${ secAngle }deg)`;

        // Using a renderer (good):
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.hrHandRef.nativeElement, 'transform', `rotate(${ hrAngle }deg)`;
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.minHandRef.nativeElement, 'transform', `rotate(${ minAngle }deg)`;
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.secHandRef.nativeElement, 'transform', `rotate(${ secAngle }deg)`;
    }
}
```

Another option could be to just add [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) on them and add 3 properties with each hand's angle on the component.